# PHP if statement comparison clarity

Tags: php

I am having a problem with PHP. I'm fairly new to it, but this is driving me batty!
The falsify() function below works. If I compare (falsify == false), then it will echo false, but why is that necessary? Why does falsify not return false without the comparison?;

```
<?php
if (falsify) {
  echo "true";
} else {
  echo "false";
}

function falsify(){
  return false;
}
?>
```

Comment: You're missing `()`, e.g., `if (falsify())`.

Comment: That's PHP being helpful; instead of throwing an error and make you upset, it will guess what you meant and make you happy. It thinks you meant `"falsify"`, while you and I know you meant `falsify()`. So it tried its best and made you confused. Happens all the time when coding PHP.

Comment: It makes perfect sense. Am I mistaken, but is this not the case in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you use an undefined constant, PHP assumes that you mean the name
>   of the constant itself, just as if you called it as a string (`CONSTANT`
>   vs `"CONSTANT"`). An error of level `E_NOTICE` will be issued when this
>   happens. See also the manual entry on why `$foo[bar]` is wrong (unless
>   you first `define() bar` as a constant) ...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php

`falsify` without the `()` is an implicit string:

```
var_dump(falsify);
var_dump(falsify());

function falsify() {
    return false;
}
```

http://codepad.org/3Kb6vcMO

Produces:

```
string(7) "falsify"
bool(false)
```

The first evaluates to `true`, hence the `if` seeing it as logically `true`.

Comment: While a confusing explanation; still the most thorough. I can't seem to mark an answer as best answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use as

```
if (falsify()){
}
```

Not sure how u did not get undefined constant error.

Comment: The OP perhaps does not have `E_NOTICE`-level reporting turned on.

Comment: yeah else it should have been detected on page load.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I am writing in WordPress, and just did a sanity check in web page. It would probably be a better sanity check if I turned on error reporting.

Comment: exactly in the dev mode it is better to turn on all the error level so that u know if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have used just *falsify* and not **falsify()** . It means falsify !=0 in php . So what is not 0 becomes true . It returns true and it ultimately becomes-

```
 if(true)
```

hence the output .